# Is this sentence has an inversion or modifying of word-order?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, inversion, subjects

I am reading an article *Tbilisi* on Wikipedia, there is a sentence that confuses with me.

> **It was in the former Viceroy of the Caucasus's palace where** the
> independence of three Transcaucasus nations – Georgia, Armenia and
> Azerbaijan – was declared by their respective national councils on 26
> to 28 May 1918.

The words' order is some kind of strange, I think the easy-to-understand order for me should be as follow:

> **The place where** independence of three Transcaucasus nations – Georgia, Armenia and
> Azerbaijan – was declared by their respective national councils on 26
> to 28 May 1918 **was in the former Viceroy of the Caucasus's palace**.

But the subject is too long, as to condense it we should change the order or make a inversion, is my thought right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not inversion. It's a cleft construction, where the dummy pronoun "it" is the subject. The PP "in the former Viceroy of the Caucasus's palace" is the foregrounded element.

Comment: *In context*, we can be pretty certain that ***former*** refers to ***palace***, not ***Viceroy*** (because "former Viceroys" aren't normally assigned a *palace*). But if it had been ***house*** rather than ***palace***, the construction would be far more ambiguous. In *that* case, it could be ***a*** house owned by someone who was once a Viceroy, OR it could be ***the*** house that used to be assigned as the "official residence" of whoever happens to be the Viceroy at any given time, for example.